# How to return an object in Three.js rather than add it to a scene? (FBXLoader)

Tags: javascript, function, three.js

If I call this function in Javascript, it works, and it adds the object to the scene:

```
var loader = new THREE.FBXLoader();

function returnFBX(PATH, scene) {
    loader.load('obj/' + PATH + '.fbx', function (object) {
        scene.add(object);
    });
}
```

However, if I replace:

```
scene.add(object);
```

with:

```
return object;
```

It seems to return undefined.

I tried using Promises, as well as the Loading Manager, but both only seem to be able to add the object to the scene, and not return an object.

I think this is because there are two nested functions within each other, as well as the loading being asynchronous. But I'm not sure how to fix this, as this is a standard way to load objects.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Just as a pointer, you could always say ```var mesh = scene.children[0]```if you know it is the first thing added to the scene to get the mesh into the main scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`load` is asynchronous - either use a callback or use await, i.e.

```
const afterload = object => { console.log(object); }

function returnFBX(PATH, scene) {
    loader.load('obj/' + PATH + '.fbx', function (object) {
        afterload(object);
    });
}
```

or

```
async function returnFBX(PATH, scene) {
    return loader.load('obj/' + PATH + '.fbx', function (object) {
        return object;
    });
}

let afterloadObject = await returnFBX( ... )
```

Comment: For the callback, how would I access the object in the end? Would I replace `console.log(object);` with `return object;`?

Comment: Not really - you have to think of it the other way around - place your logic inside `afterload`

Comment: you could also return the promise (`load`) from `returnFBX` and chain a `then` onto it - let me know if you'd like to see an example of that

Comment: I can do things such as adding the object to the scene in `afterload` but if I want to access the object outside of this function, I'm not sure how. For instance, if I want to change the scale of the object later on, it would be nice to call something like `object.scale.set(5,5,5);`. Would this be possible with the callback?

Comment: you can declare a variable outside `returnFBX` and set it inside the callback.

Comment: Don't think I'm doing this correctly. If I declare a variable outside called `var mesh;` and then inside `afterload` set `mesh = object; scene.add(mesh);`, then it adds the mesh to the scene once I call `returnFBX('myfile', scene)` in my `init()` function. However, if I try to change the scale of the mesh in my `init()` function after calling `returnFBX()`, by doing `mesh.scale.set(5,5,5);` it doesn't do anything, meaning it probably executes that line of code before the object has been added to the scene in the callback.

Comment: Nevermind, I guess it doesn't really matter if I can't change the object in the `init()` if I just use functions to make changes to the object throughout, and call them in `afterload`. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

**This is how i did it with**  `loadAsync()`

```
async function LoadModel (...) {
  const result = await loader.loadAsync(...);
  return result;
}

const model = await LoadModel(...);
```

check how you can wait for object loader: [here](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/wait-for-object-loader/30573)